# If $X$ is uniform on $(-1,1)$, find $g(x)$, so that $Y = g(X)$ has pdf $f_Y (y) = 2e^{-2y}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

> If $X$ is uniformly distributed in $(-1, 1)$, find $g(x)$, so that the random variable $Y = g(X)$ may
>   have the density function $f_Y (y) = 2e^{-2y}, \  y > 0.$

Suppose $g:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be a monotonically increasing function such that $Y=g(X)$.

Let $a \in (-1,1)$ and $b=g(a)$. Therefore we have $$P(Y \leq b)=P(X \leq a) $$

$P(Y \leq b) =\int_0^b 2e^{-2y} dy = 1-e^{-2b} $ and $P(X \leq a) = \frac{a+1}{2}$ (X is uniform).

Therefore $1-e^{-2b}=\frac{a+1}{2}$. Hence $b = -\frac{1}{2} \log (\frac{1-a}{2})$.

Therefore $$ g(x) = -\frac{1}{2} \log (\frac{1-x}{2}). $$

Is this correct? Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks good. Here is another explanation that may give you another perspective of the steps that you have taken.

In general if $F_Y$ is the CDF of a random variable $Y$, then the random variable $F_Y(Y)$ follows the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. (See [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Definition).)
Then $2F_Y(Y)-1$ is uniform on $(-1,1)$

The CDF of $Y$ is $F_Y(y) = 1 - e^{-2y}$, so $X = 2(1-e^{-2Y})-1$ is uniform on $(-1,1)$. Inverting this yields the function $g(x)=-\frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1-x}{2}$, which is the same as yours.